# Set command is not working with the variable value

Tags: linux, freeswitch

I am setting the variable like this

```
action application="set" data="RESULT=${system sed -n 1p /nfs/th/play/${uuid}}" inline="true"
```

Here I am trying to assign the wav file path to the variable, but here the problem is it is getting assigned as

```
2014-05-08 13:34:56.659049 [DEBUG] mod_dptools.c:1402 sofia/internal/1002@192.168.0.106 SET [RESULT]=[/usr/local/freeswitch/sounds/en/us/callie/directory/8000/dir-for_prev.wav
```

]

The variable `RESULT` is not being set properly.  The closing square bracket is coming to the new line as it should be in the same line immediately after the path.  So while playing the wav file it is showing the error as

```
2014-05-08 13:34:56.679046 [ERR] switch_core_file.c:150 Invalid file format [wav

] for [/usr/local/freeswitch/sounds/en/us/callie/directory/8000/dir-for_prev.wav

]!
```

Even though I write the sed command in shell script and execute it here in Freeswitch I am facing the same problem.

Can anyone help me in solving this issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would use mod_perl instead. The Perl interpreter is then permanently loaded in the memory, and it takes only a couple of milliseconds to load the script, parse and execute it. The only problem, you can't execute perl application in inline action. But you can get around it by reorganizing the dialplan.

You can also give control completely to your perl script and call transfer or bridge or whatever you do from there.

I have a perl script which opens a local mysql connection, looks up the caller number, and then transfers further to the dialplan. It takes less than 10ms to process.